# How did this website hide its html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, angularjs

I ran into this website and I looked at it's source code.

[DCARD](https://www.dcard.tw/f)

[ther are screen shots here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5hsk.jpg)

I am sorry that the language is Chinese.

This website i kind of like  forum in my country.And the wierd thing that I found is that the all the topics(threads)that I am able to click is not showing in the html.(Meaning that I cant see any hyperlink that link to any other page in the html source code.)Didnt the browser parse the html first and then its being able to show the contents to user?How did it actually do it?Is this done by angular js or what.

Comment: I'm able to view the source code.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Yeah, as you can see in the web source code, it uses angular as their js framework. And they implement SPA for the web.

Comment: The source code shows how the page initially is. So generated HTML may not be there, you can find it by right-clicking the element and selecting "Inspect Element". The HTML isn't hidden, your are just looking at the initial source code, not what's on the page after everything is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a SPA angular APP. So that's angular handling all the routes instead of traditional URLs.

Comment: "all the routes instead of traditional URLs" --- this phrase is misleading